# How to determine if the data is encrypted OR signed with an attached signature?

Tags: .net, c#-2.0, .net-standard-2.0, pkcs#7, smime

I have an S/MIME email which is signed with an attached signature and has the Content-Type header as below:

```
Content-Type: application/pkcs7-mime;
    smime-type="enveloped-data";
    name="smime.p7m"
```

This value is wrong, signed-only emails must have `smime-type="signed-data"`, not `smime-type="enveloped-data"` which is for encrypted content. So, my code cannot process it. But Outlook and Thunderbird deal with it just fine. I wonder how. I guess there is a way to derive the type of data (encrypted or signed) from its contents.

Looking into `EnvelopedCms` or `SignedCms` classes didn't let me find anything suitable. They expect me to know the type of the data upfront. Perhaps, I could use some low-level stuff like Win32 API for that but I'd prefer to use a high-level API which is platform independent (I need to cover a wide range of .NET platforms from .NET 2.0 to the modern .NET Core editions).

If it's possible with a third-party library like Bouncy Castle, it won't work for me. I need a code which can be fully incorporated into mine, with no extra dependencies.

Comment: So you _know_ the email is signed? Is it clear-text signed or perhaps opaque signed, which would look like encrypted?

Comment: @not2savvy Yes, I know that it's opaque signed or encrypted but can't distinguish which one of these (because content-type header is wrong). Both look similarly. I guess I can decode it manually and determine this, without .NET API (PKCS7 format is well-defined), but I'd prefer to rely on .NET API whenever possible.